# Handle modifications in a diff file

Tags: python, regex, diff

I've got a diff file and I want to handle adds/deletions/modifications to update an SQL database.

```
+NameA|InfoA1|InfoA2
-NameB|InfoB1|InfoB2
+NameB|InfoB3|InfoB2
-NameC|InfoC1|InfoC2
-NameD|InfoD1|InfoD2
-NameE|InfoE1|InfoE2
+NameD|InfoD1|InfoD3
+NameE|InfoE3|InfoE2
```

With a Python script, I first detect two following lines with a regular expressions to handle modifications like B.

```
re.compile(r"^-(.+?)\|(.*?)\|(.+?)\n\+(.+?)\|(.*?)\|(.+?)(?:\n|\Z)", re.MULTILINE)
```

I delete all the matching lines, and then rescan my file and then handle all of them like additions/deletions.
My problem is with lines like D & E. For the moment I treat them like two deletions, then two additions, and I've got consequences of CASCADE DELETE in my SQL database, as I should treat them as modifications.

How can I handle such modifications D & E?

The diff file is generated by a bash script before, I could handle it differently if needed.

Comment: This is not a good application of regexp. Just iterate through the lines, recording deletions and additions in dictionaries. If a key is in both dictionaries, it's a modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> a = '''
+NameA|InfoA1|InfoA2
-NameB|InfoB1|InfoB2
+NameB|InfoB3|InfoB2
-NameC|InfoC1|InfoC2
-NameD|InfoD1|InfoD2
-NameE|InfoE1|InfoE2
+NameD|InfoD1|InfoD3
+NameE|InfoE3|InfoE2
'''
>>> diff = {}
>>> for row in a.splitlines():
    if not row:
        continue
    s = row.split('|')
    name = s[0][1:]
    data = s[1:]
    if row.startswith('+'):
        change = diff.get(name, {'rows': []})
        change['rows'].append(row)
        change['status'] = 'modified' if change.has_key('status') else 'added'
    else:
        change = diff.get(name, {'rows': []})
        change['rows'].append(row)
        change['status'] = 'modified' if change.has_key('status') else 'removed'
    diff[name] = change

>>> def print_by_status(status=None):
for item, value in diff.items():
    if status is not None and status == value['status'] or status is None:
        print '\nStatus: %s\n%s' % (value['status'], '\n'.join(value['rows']))
>>> print_by_status(status='added')

Status: added
+NameA|InfoA1|InfoA2
>>> print_by_status(status='modified')

Status: modified
-NameD|InfoD1|InfoD2
+NameD|InfoD1|InfoD3

Status: modified
-NameE|InfoE1|InfoE2
+NameE|InfoE3|InfoE2

Status: modified,
-NameB|InfoB1|InfoB2
+NameB|InfoB3|InfoB2
```

In this case you will have dictionary with all collected data with diff status and rows. You can do with current dict whatever you want.